# Sound Design Education In NZ

Tags: sound-design, education, post-production

i am working in sound editing and mixing field for 6 years,besides i have analyzed hundreds of movies M&E Tracks and re-made some of them as an exercise,
But i need to know more about sound designing and work at Professional and international level, So I am Going to study and taking internships in NZ or AUSTRALIA,
I have researched about the schools there But Could you Guide me If You know any better idea for studying in NZ or maybe taking internships in the studios there , do you know any studios there?

finally whats your offer as an professional person in this field and how can i get raised to work at international level?

Thanks for Guidance,

Answer (score 2):

If Australia is an option, then you could check out AFTRS. The current head of sound taught me while i was there, and he's an amazing guy, probably the best teacher i've ever had. The course, i've heard, isn't as good as it used to be, and is more expensive, but it's still very cheap in comparison to USA film schools. And they do have fantastic people teaching sound. not to mention the gear you get to play with.

As far as internships go, you could try Big Bang or Huzzah in Sydney; or Music and Effects or Soundfirm in Melbourne. They're all very nice, so if you're polite but persistent, you could get a shot.

Comment: @reoger. I Searched about AFTRS But the fees are same with Nz schools,may i have your email for more guidance and sharing information, thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware there are no sound design schools in NZ - most of my friends who work in film sound post went to film school, since understanding the entire process of film making is a very important part of being a film sound editor.

With regards to becoming a sound designer, theres no need for me to repeat what I wrote elsewhere at SSD, do some searches but read also this:

[Paths to Pro work?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/284)

Just a note: NZ is a very small country, 4 million people and probably a total of a dozen working film sound editors total, with maybe 5 of those who work as supervising sound editors and 3 as sound designers. There are also plenty of young local people here wanting internships.... As per my comments in that other thread, most people who work in film sound got years of experience working in TV sound post first.

Comment: @tim: Thanks for your complete Reply, So You Think NZ is the wrong place to start sound designing at professional level? So whats your advise for a person like me who there is no chance for working at international level in his local area? Thanks

Comment: If you read that post I linked to I think you would understand that working as a "sound designer" at an international level does not happen by moving to another country to study. It may well be the start of a 5 - 10 year process to achieve that goal but don't move to NZ (which is about as far away from anywhere as possible) or Australia expecting to find an instant solution. The AFTRS has a great reputation (there is nothing in NZ like it) and after a year or two study/experience there you may be ready for a trainnee/assistant position.....