# Where do I Begin in Sound Design?

Tags: career, design

Hi I wonder if you folks on this site can help me out. I just graduated from university doing Digital Media. For my honours project I did sound design for a short animated film and it’s given me the idea that this is what I want to pursue as a career path. The thing is I don’t really have a clue where to begin. What’s the first step I should take? Please any advice is much appreciated.

This is the sound design I did for my honours project so you know the kind of level I’m on.
https://vimeo.com/65973338

Answer (score 1):

I mean, your demo material is really pretty terrific man. Start seeking some full scale and/or short films or start searching out some game devs if that's a path you want to pursue. It looks like you have the technical end of it together, the business end of it is sort of the hard part. In Philadephia, we have a film office that will occasionally host panels and mixer events where you can meet people of different disciplines. Maybe see if your area has an equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Get a job.

Echoing what Dave said, the craft is not really the difficult part of this business, it's the business. If you're thinking of doing sound design for longer as your main pursuit, then you need to find someone or something that's willing to pay for your services and continue to look for opportunities, because many projects are temporary. I.e. you need to find a way that enables you to do sound design for others. You can look for positions in  established studios (unlikely), look for gigs as a freelancer (difficult, but the most usual option), look for positions in media companies (the most secure/profitable, but usually loads of equally good applicants and very few positions) or just work on sound on the side while doing something else to get food on the table.

Also, you need to create a presence (in the public, in the web, among your friends). You need to get your voice out there that says "I'm a sound guy, I can do sound for your project!". That's a start into making yourself a person that people who need sound design services start to contact.

Also, when you start to do projects with/for others: always do your best work, always give the best service that you can. Your reputation will be built on how good work you do and how easy or fun you're to work with. Remember that there's nothing more to your work than how good it sounds, was it delivered on time and on budget and how easy you were to work with, that's what generally matters to the clients.

Good luck.

Edit:

Also, build a portfolio from the work that you've done and put it in the web. Keep updating it when new work gets done. The portfolio is what you use to sell your services to people or what a prospective employer will be interested in.

Answer (score 1):

using the search function might be a good starting point, for example:

[Paths to Pro work?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/284)

which motivated me to write this:

http://www.musicofsound.co.nz/blog/career-advice-part-2